# Passing variable from batch to text

Tags: blackberry, text, batch-file

I've found lots of examples of how to pass a variable from a text file to a batch file, but I am looking for something the other way around..

This is using fledgecontroller to do a simulated test on the blackberry.

My batch would ask for the user input:

```
set filename=
set /p filename=Please enter file name: 
echo ""
echo %filename%>screen.txt
FledgeController.exe /session=test < screen.txt > out.txt
```

and I want my textfile to read the variable from the batch file

```
SaveLcdSnapshot("\\screenshots\\%filename%_test.png")
```

Is there any possible way to call the variable from batch into a txt and use that variable in the txt file when running the test?

Answer (score 0):

Your textfile can't read anything, it is a textfile.
But your batch can replace something (or create) the complete textfile.

```
set filename=
set /p filename=Please enter file name: 
echo "" 
echo SaveLcdSnapshot("\screenshots\%filename%_test.png")  > screen.txt
FledgeController.exe /session=test < screen.txt > out.txt
```